# Record raw data on Labview

Tags: labview, logitech

I have this VI in Labview that streams video from a webcam (Logitech C300) and processes the colored layers of each image as arrays. I am trying to get raw Bayer data from the webcam using Logitech's program (http://web.archive.org/web/20100830135714/http://www.quickcamteam.net/documentation/how-to/how-to-enable-raw-streaming-on-logitech-webcams) and the Vision Acquisition tool but I only get as much data as with regular capture, instead of four times more.

Basically, I get 1280x1024 24-bit pixels where I want 1280*1024 32-bit or 2560*2048 8-bit pixels.

Has anyone had any experience with this and knows a way for Labview to process the camera's raw output, or how to actually record a raw file from the camera?

Thank you!

[image: Labview code]

Comment: Which camera acquisition modes have you used for raw and regular capture? Specifically, the link you provided has a table for sample image size calculations.

Comment: I am using continuous acquisition with inline processing and get a 24 bit image out of the vision acquisition module instead of the expected 32 bits

Comment: LabVIEW typically uses its own driver for camera acquisition. Have you configured the acquisition to use a raw mode from LabVIEW? It would help if you could post your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The driver flag you've enabled simply packs the raw pixel value (8/10 bpp) into the least significant bits of the 24bit values. Assuming that the 8bpp mode is used, the raw values can be extracted from the blue color plane as in the following example. It can then be debayered to obtain RGB values for example.

[image: Extract B and debayer]

Unless you can improve on the debayer algorithms in the firmware, or have very specific needs this is not very useful. Normally, one can at least reduce the amount of data transferred by enabling raw mode - which is not the case here.

The above assumes that the raw video mode isn't being overwritten by the LabVIEW IMAQdx driver. If that is the case, you might be able to enable raw mode from LabVIEW through property nodes. This requires to manually configure the acquision, as the configurability of express VIs are limited. Use the EnumStrings property to get all possible attributes, and then see if there is something like the one specified outside of the diagram disable structure (this is from a different camera).

[image: Raw acquisition IMAQdx]